# Exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' was thrown. while sitecore getfallback language

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sitecore

I am developing sitecore application. I set the website properties in config file.I 'm getting above error while getfallbacklanguage method while accessing fallback property value.if I retrieved value using property index I am getting value in quick watch but while property name I m getting attached error.

[image]

Comment: Can you show the property `Properties["FallbackLanguange"]` code?

Comment: Also look at the StackTrace in the exception details as that might give you a good clue as to what is happening.

Comment: Do you make use of Properties that takes the value of the FallbackLanguage? Also, can you share the stacktrace and code